# Print full filename in tabs when using terminal Vim

Tags: terminal, tabbed-user-interface

I use Vim 8.0 (homebrew) from iTerm 3.

How do I use full filenames instead of these abominations that Vim seems to print by default? [image]

Some context as filenames:

- sidebar.php
- sponsors.php
- donate.php
- sort-bar.php
- single-product.php
- archive-product.php
- product-box.php
- templates.js
- card-page.php

So yeah, these serve basically no value. I can't guess which "uct.php" is what I want. How do I make Vim print the full filenames (leave folders and path out)?

I researched before asking the question, and none of the answers provided in these worked for me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256380/show-filename-only-in-tabs-terminal-vim
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468939/how-to-let-tab-display-only-file-name-rather-than-the-full-path-in-vim

Comment: where do you see those filenames? Could it be, that this comes from a plugin you use?

Comment: In the "tab bar" or whatever it is, that appears on top then I open files using `:tabe filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the terminal, you want to check the 'tabline' option. For the gui version, check the 'guitablabel' setting. Since you seem to be using a terminal vim, here is what I would do:

The help page for ['tabline'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27tabline%27) the help already mentions how to set it, so follow the link [setting-tabline](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#setting-tabline) and copy the function found there:

```
  function MyTabLine()
      let s = ''
      for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
        " select the highlighting
        if i + 1 == tabpagenr()
          let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
        else
          let s .= '%#TabLine#'
        endif

        " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
        let s .= '%' . (i + 1) . 'T'

        " the label is made by MyTabLabel()
        let s .= ' %{MyTabLabel(' . (i + 1) . ')} '
      endfor

      " after the last tab fill with TabLineFill and reset tab page nr
      let s .= '%#TabLineFill#%T'

      " right-align the label to close the current tab page
      if tabpagenr('$') > 1
        let s .= '%=%#TabLine#%999Xclose'
      endif

      return s
    endfunction

    function MyTabLabel(n)
      let buflist = tabpagebuflist(a:n)
      let winnr = tabpagewinnr(a:n)
      return bufname(buflist[winnr - 1])
    endfunction

    :set tabline=%!MyTabLine()
```

Now, since you want to have the fullname, make the second last line of the `MyTabLabel()` function this:

`return fnamemodify(bufname(buflist[winnr - 1]), ':t')`

or if you want to see the whole path:

`return fnamemodify(bufname(buflist[winnr - 1]), ':p')`

Read more about the [fnamemodify() function](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#fnamemodify%28%29)
and the various arguments it accepts at [filename-modifiers](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers)

Comment: Works fine! I'll have some reading to do. Thanks.